# design principle

Tags: design-patterns

what is the difference between below two design principles?

1. " program to an interface, not an implementation" and
2. " depend upon abstraction, do not depend upon concrete class".

these two principle saying the same thing but in two different ways.

Comment: This type of question would be better for programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6):

Interface is an abstraction of a concrete class, so 2. is a subset of 1. The principle 1. has wider applicability (you can use it for any kind of interface, not only those used in object-oriented programming).

Comment: if we can use principle1 then why there is principle 2. dont you think it create more confusion?

Comment: @Mahendra Athneria Sadly, that is the reality. Many people refer to the same concept under different names. I would love to have each concept tagged with a GUID and searchable in a database, but alas!

Answer (score 2):

They are essentally saying the same thing in different words.

You should write your class so that it depends on an abstract idea (like an interface) instead of a concrete implementation of an idea.  This allows you to change behavior in pieces instead of having to re-write whole chunks of code.

See Dependancy Injection.

**Example:**

```
public class Chef : IResturauntWorker 
{
    // This is an example of writing to an interface instead of an
    // an implementation.  Because the Chef class implements the 
    // IResturauntWorker interface, the chef can be swapped in with other
    // resturaunt workers like bussers or waiters.

    public void Chop(Carrot c)
    {
        // code to chop a carrot

        // this is an example of depending on an implementation
        // because Carrot is a concrete class, this method can 
        // only be used with a Carrot
    }

    public void Chop(IVegetable c)
    {
        // code to chop a Vegetable

        // this is an example of depending on an abstraction
        // because IVegetable is a abstraction of an idea 
        // (a vegetable, in this case), this method can be
        // used with any class that implements IVegetable,
        // including carrots, celery, onions, etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: if both are the same thing in different words then why these two are different principle in Design patterns?

Comment: An interface is an abstraction, and an concrete class is an implementation.  You should write your code so that it is/can be abstracted easily, and you shouldn't depend on a concrete implementation of a class in your code to allow implementations to be defined and used whereever the abstraction is expected.  If you're not familar with dependancy injection, then I recommend researching that, as its an important principle that demonstates these (and requires) the principles that you quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Interface is nothing but providing mean to communicate diffrent types of implementation
Abstraction nothing but creating generic class with some abstract method.

Answer (score 0):

In the object-oriented world, these terms used frequently and interchangeably.
Interface is nothing but abstraction and implementation is nothing but concrete.